# How to read multiple lines of a file into one row of a dataframe

Tags: r, file

I have a data file where individual samples are seperated by a blank line and each field is on  it's own line:

```
age 20
weight 185
height 72

age 87
weight 109
height 60

age 15
weight 109
height 58

...
```

How can I read this file into a dataframe such that each row represents a sample with columns of age, weight, height?

```
    age    weight    height

1   20      185        72  
2   87      109        60
3   15      109        58
...
```

Comment: the `age`, `weight` etc... are values or are they like: `age 20` and in the next line `weight 185`...?

Comment: Fixed the question, should be clear from the example now.

Comment: grrrr...   it's not the place for "it's"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@user1317221_G showed the approach I would take, but resorted to loading an extra package and explicitly generating the groups. The groups (the ID variable) is the key to getting any `reshape` type answer to work. The matrix answers don't have that limitation.

Here's a closely related approach in base R:

```
mydf <- read.table(header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                   text = "age 20
                   weight 185
                   height 72

                   age 87
                   weight 109
                   height 60

                   age 15
                   weight 109
                   height 58
                   ")

# Create your id variable
mydf <- within(mydf, {
  id <- ave(V1, V1, FUN = seq_along)
})
```

With an id variable, your transformation is easy:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = "id", timevar="V1")
#   id V2.age V2.weight V2.height
# 1  1     20       185        72
# 4  2     87       109        60
# 7  3     15       109        58
```

Or:

```
# Your ids become the "rownames" with this approach
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(V2 ~ id + V1, mydf))
#   age height weight
# 1  20     72    185
# 2  87     60    109
# 3  15     58    109
```

Comment: +1 `ave` is good choice and I like the `xtabs` solution that I always forget about.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @BlueMagister's answer you can use scan with some options to read this directly into a list, then convert the list to a data frame:

```
tmp <- scan(text = "
age     20
weight  185
height  72

age     87
weight  109
height  60

age     15
weight  109
height  58", multi.line=TRUE, 
  what=list('',0,'',0,'',0), 
  blank.lines.skip=TRUE)

mydf <- as.data.frame( tmp[ c(FALSE,TRUE) ] )
names(mydf) <- sapply( tmp[ c(TRUE,FALSE) ], '[', 1 )
```

This assumes that the variables within a record are always in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(text ="
age     1
weight  1
height  6

age     2
weight  7
height  2

age     4
weight  8
height  9", header=FALSE) 

df$ID <- rep(1:3, each=3)
library(reshape2)
newdf <- dcast(df, ID~V1, value.var="V2")

#     ID age height weight
#1  1   1      6      1
#2  2   2      2      7
#3  3   4      9      8
```

Comment: +1. This is the approach that came to my mind too. I don't like having to "hard-code" the ID variable the way you did though.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Your right, I although we could go a step further with to automation with: `df$ID <- rep(1:(length(df[,1])/3), each=3)`

Comment: That's more like it! Good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution

```
data <- readLines('c:\\relatorios\\bla.txt') # Read the data
data <- data[data != ''] # Remove the white lines
names <- unique(gsub('[0-9]*','',data)) # Get the names
data <- matrix(as.real(gsub('[^0-9]*','',data)),ncol=3,byrow=T) # Create matrix
colnames(data) <- names # Set the names
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I've tried with `scan`:

```
##substitute text with file depending on your input
##read in three strings separated by spaces, multi-line input
y <- scan(text=x,what=list(character(),character(),character())
  ,sep="\n",multi.line=TRUE)
##combine into a matrix of strings
y <- do.call(cbind,y)
#     [,1]     [,2]         [,3]       
#[1,] "age 20" "weight 185" "height 72"
#[2,] "age 87" "weight 109" "height 60"
#[3,] "age 15" "weight 109" "height 58"
##set column names based on text from the first row
colnames(y) <- regmatches(y[1,],regexpr("^\\w+",y[1,]))
##remove non-numeric characters
y <- gsub("\\D+","",y)
##convert to number format, preserving matrix structure
y <- apply(y,2,as.numeric)
##convert to data frame (if necessary)
y <- data.frame(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source file has these three variables all the way down, one simple way is just to read the file in as two colunns (names in first, numbers in second), and then turn the second column into a matrix.  If I snitch the `df` from user1317221_G's answer,

```
matrix(df$V2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    6
[2,]    2    7    2
[3,]    4    8    9
```

Adding row and/or column names is trivial. Sorry about getting the column order "age,weight,height" :-)