# Transpose every N rows to new column

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a df with hundreds of row within a single column following this pattern:

```
   col1
1.12/17/18
2.10/10
3.Best Movie
4.This is the best movie ever...
5.
6.
7.1/1/2019
8.02/10
9.Worst Movie
10.This movie was awful...
```

I was wondering if there is a way to transpose every row within the range of 4 rows into their own columns, and then subsequently stack the next range of 4 underneath the new columns?

So the final output looks like:

```
Date         Rating     Title       Review
12/17/18      10/10     Best Movie  This is the best movie ever...
1/1/2019      02/10     Worst Movie This movie was awful...
```

any suggestions, as to how I can alter the df to acheive this?

Comment: I would add to @alistaire's solution that you might want to begin by filtering out the blank lines (5-6 in your example).

Comment: Very similar to this old question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582422/how-to-read-multiple-lines-of-a-file-into-one-row-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a long-to-wide transformation, but you need to create a key column (which will become column names) and an ID column so it's clear which values go into which rows. In tidyverse grammar,

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("12/17/18", "10/10", "Best Movie", "This is the best movie ever...", "", "", "1/1/2019", "02/10", "Worst Movie", "This movie was awful..."), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df %>% 
    filter(col1 != '') %>%    # drop empty rows
    mutate(key = rep(c('Date', 'Rating', 'Title', 'Review'), n() / 4), 
           id = cumsum(key == 'Date')) %>% 
    spread(key, col1)
#>   id     Date Rating                         Review       Title
#> 1  1 12/17/18  10/10 This is the best movie ever...  Best Movie
#> 2  2 1/1/2019  02/10        This movie was awful... Worst Movie
```

This data structure is really fragile, though; any deviation can throw it all off. A better solution is to maintain data structure upstream, before it ends up in this mess.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just wrap this into a `matrix` first if you have the same number of columns for each record. Using @alistaire's data:

```
out <- as.data.frame(matrix(df$col1[df$col1!=""], ncol=4, byrow=TRUE))
names(out) <- c('Date', 'Rating', 'Title', 'Review')
out
#      Date Rating       Title                         Review
#1 12/17/18  10/10  Best Movie This is the best movie ever...
#2 1/1/2019  02/10 Worst Movie        This movie was awful...
```

Or even use the `multi.line=TRUE` argument of `scan` to pull it together all in one go:

```
out <- data.frame(scan(text=df$col1[df$col1 != ""], multi.line=TRUE, what=rep(list(""), 4), sep="\n"))
names(out) <- c('Date', 'Rating', 'Title', 'Review')
out
#      Date Rating       Title                         Review
#1 12/17/18  10/10  Best Movie This is the best movie ever...
#2 1/1/2019  02/10 Worst Movie        This movie was awful...
```

The benefit of `scan` is that you can also specify the output format in the `what=` argument. So if column 2 was an integer you could do:

```
scan(file, multi.line=TRUE, what=list("",1L,"",""), sep="\n")
```